# Detect whether ISP gave me public IP address

Tags: ip, ip-address, isp

How do you detect if your ISP actually gave you a public ip address(static or dynamic)? I mean they must have given me a public ip but how do I know if they did not secretly made me to share it with another user?

I have a dynamic public ip address and I am behind my router. I usually check whether ISP is still keeping my public ip address by hosting teamspeak or hfs or other software like apache/filezilla servers and then joining the server using public ip.

Is there any better way to do this? Can you detect that ISP is not giving you public ip by using tracert command?

Comment: How are you checking your public IP address? Is this the address your router is getting? If so, it is your IP... No one else can have the same IP address in the same network. If you are sharing a public IP address you would have to have a NAT address from private space.

Comment: @acejavelin "If you are sharing a public IP address" -> [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)

Comment: [How would I test to see if I'm behind carrier grade or regular NAT?](http://superuser.com/q/713422)

Comment: @DavidPostill I understand Carrier-grade NAT... intimately... but you will not get a public IP address directly at your router if you are in this scenario, your router would get an address in private IP space. From your link: "Carrier-grade NAT (CGN), also known as large-scale NAT (LSN), is an approach to IPv4 network design in which end sites, in particular residential networks, are configured with *private network addresses* that are translated to public IPv4 addresses"

Comment: I am checking my public IP by going to google or speedtest.net. 
How do I know my router is getting public IP? because there is no way to tell. Employees of the ISP have set my router for russian/PPPoE mode. They did not insert any static IP address in router settings menu. @acejavelin

Comment: @acejavelin You are still effectively sharing a public IP address - the same one as all the other customers on the same "local" network. CGN just moves your public IP address from your router WAN port to somewhere upstream in the ISP network.

Comment: @NajeebTaher Getting your IP address statically or dynamically has no effect, and is no indication, of whether it is a public or private IP address.

Comment: @David Postill That is exactly what I was saying... if from your ISP your router is getting a public IP directly, you are not sharing it, if it is getting a private IP then you likely are.

Comment: @acejavelin I know, that's why I was asking. Because my router has to lag into my ISP's system with certain username and password. How do I know ISP is still assigning me a public IP (which is not shared with other users).

Comment: @NajeebTaher Doesn't your router have a status page that shows your WAN IP address?

Comment: Yes the status page shows a public IP as my IP address. Does this means ISP is not sharing my public IP with another user? (it also shows same IP as default gateway)