# How can i find the ISP IP allocated to my Router?

Tags: networking, nat

I am using Router to connect to internet. How can i find the ip address allocated to my router by isp in windows 7? I cant use [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/) since it will give shared ip if i am behind a CGN.

Comment: Traceroute maybe? From command prompt, run `tracert google.com`

Comment: What router ? The router itself should display it.

Comment: @Lawrence I would like to know any generic approaches. So router information is not necessary.

Comment: @masegaloeh if i use tracert, i am gettin loads of ips. Probably proxies between me and google. From that how i can find which ip belongs to my router.

Comment: @Kumar Try looking **first public** IP on your tracert command

Comment: @masegaloeh but isn't the tracert shows router's loacal ip instead of  ip allocated by ISP? pls differ with my answer..

Comment: It will contain mixed of public and local ip. See example [here](https://support.orcsweb.com/KB/a297/ping-and-trace-route.aspx). The first public ip of traceroute results is **24.224.96.1**, so that ip of public router.

Comment: If your ISP is using CGN, then your router would only display a private IP issued by your ISP, inaccessible from outside their network. *Why* do you want this information? It's useless for pretty much any situation. We may be able to help more if we know the actual problem (see: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: @masegaloeh `tracert` or `traceroute` will not always show the router's external IP.

Comment: The "generic" approach is to log in to the router to see the assigned IP address of the WAN interface.

Answer (score 1):

Its an ugly ugly solution but the best place to check this is at your router - it will tell you the exact ip address that's been assigned to it. I used to have a script that would scrape it off my older router since it exposed that information without needing to log on.

If you're behind CGN (the horrible horrible thing that it is), there's a limited range of ip address that are allocated for it as you'd see here - the [answer here](https://superuser.com/a/713431/10165) covers the process of finding out if its the case.

If you suspect you're behind a proxy, like [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/709459/what-is-the-actual-ip-address-of-my-computer/709466#709466) here - I've found the [lagado proxy tes](http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test)t to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
cmd
```

run

```
ipconfig
```

to see your machine's IP, say it a.b.c.d , so your router address assuming is a.b.c.1  and double check it as was advised by

```
tracert
```

yes, and sorry, if you are after assigned IP by ISP to router, can you log in to the router and look for it there? If it is static and was set by ISP you can find it there most likely. If it is dynamic, nos sure the router can show it. But anyways `tracert` should.

Comment: not that ip. The ip allocated by ISP.

Comment: I added a little but to my answer.

Comment: but isn't the tracert shows router's loacal ip instead of ip allocated by ISP? pls differ with my answer..

Comment: tracert will not always show the router's external IP.

Comment: Traceroute won't show you the router's external IP. It'll show you the router's *internal* IP and then whatever the next hop is, which is more likely whatever you're connected to on the ISP's end.